Error in latex template
I have an error when I was trying to turn on my latex template. This is "Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "exam.fund 1".tex" Any help?

Please [edit] your question and give us more detail. What is the template you are trying to compile? Can you give us a minimal example that reproduces the problem? What command are you running that gives you this error? What operating system are you running? Why .exe? Are you on Windows? If so, are you using Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Please add more details about how you are trying to compile the document.

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting. Take the [tour].
